# Controlling keyboard content shift behaviour

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard

I have following content layout on a page:

[image: UI layout]

Then text is entered into input box, keyboard appears and *1. Fixed header* is shited up:

[image: UI layout 2]

How can I make area *1. Fixed header* really fixed, so it's not moved by keyboard?

**Update 1**: [solution #1](http://sorokoletov.com/2011/08/windows-phone-70-handling-text-entry-screens/), however I find it rather cumbersome and complex to implement. If there any other ways I will be happy to see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly go through this example we have to do some manual works as this issue is because of the default property of keyboard in wp7

http://sorokoletov.com/2011/08/windows-phone-70-handling-text-entry-screens/